# When the slope of the angle bisector is 1, is the product of the slopes of the 2 lines forming the angle equal to 1

Tags: geometry, angle, slope

When the slope of the angle bisector is 1, I have been told that the product of the slopes of the 2 lines forming the original angle is 1. Is this true?

Comment: I think this is true expect for when the two lines are x and y axis.

Comment: Yes, it's true. You should draw a picture to convince yourself why, and answer your own question below.

Comment: thanks looking for a proof if there is one

Comment: the tangent of the two lines are reciprocals - it is easy to show it.